# Как вернуть фокус в начало текста в JTextPane?

Tags: java, swing

После вывода текста в JTextPane, необходимо вернуть фокус в начало текста, а потом переместить фокус на кнопку.
Чтобы долго не объяснять, вот две картинки. Сейчас в результате поиска слов приложение выглядит как на картинке слева, а нужно сделать, чтобы выглядело как на картинке справа.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно такое сделать?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Похоже, что Вам нужно это: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#setCaretPosition(int)

Код:

```
textPane.setCaretPosition(0);
```

Comment: То, что надо! Большое спасибо!

Comment: @AliceMagic, рад помочь!